# MySQL set server to run not externally for internet

Tags: mysql, binding, ip, public, internal

I know, that if I want I could run my application ( C++ or .NET ) , which I've developed internally. I mean, I have an external IP for my PC, but for the security reasons I don't want my application to be seen, so for it, I just set NOT an external IP for the part where I'm binding an IP for a socket, that listening. That is the way how I did my application be seen only internally.

But what for the MySQL server? I scanned my server and see, that MySQL 3306 port is seen. I think it's bad. How can I hide MySQL Server from the public and make it ineternally seen?

Comment: its called a firewall

Comment: @x4rf41 firewall? Have you read how I hide my .net/C++ apps? I have an ip both internal and external and just bind to the internal ip, so on this way my app was hidden from the public and NO firewall exists on my PC. Isn't such a way for the MySQL binding existing?

Comment: maybe there is, i dont know, but the usual solution to this problem is a firewall. i dont see a reason why you would do that within the application.

Comment: @x4rf41 I don't know how some commercial firewalls do their work. For e.g. Kaspersky soft wasn't great for me and it occurs more new problems than make my server more secure. Than also by a logic firewalls must set limits for the IP access and etc on the similar way. Also *nix admins as I know often may not to use some firewalls,  I heard about SELinux, but many friends, which works as admins told me that they don't use it and many features could be set by a system.

Comment: @x4rf41 also , it does refer for the NT ( Win family ), if you work not at administer account ( not root in Win ) , all you could set and make to work and does refer for the firewall on Windows, they repeat setting/binding function as you can do by yourself and it's very difficult. As for the MySQL I haven't see how I can make a socket fork and just set internally from MySQL config-files.